# PHP:Set Data in option menu using php and getting data from a file and the option menu is already created using php

Tags: php, html

This is how my option menu is created in html

```
<select id="state" class="form-control input-sm" disabled name="state" class="form-control input-sm">
<option value="">Select State</option>
<?php                           $file=fopen('../data_entry_form/data/state.txt','r');
while($input = fgets($file)){
$states=@split(':',$input);
echo '<option value="'.$states[0].'">'.$states[1].'</option>';
}
fclose($file);
?>
</select>
```

now i want to match value in $state to the value above created option menu and it get selected on the html page please help me

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to understand what you want exactly, but from what I understand you want to include the [selected](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) tag.

Basically:

```
$selected = (/*some condition when true*/) ? "selected" : "";
echo '<option $selected value="'.$states[0].'">'.$states[1].'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Try this:
<html>
<select id="state" class="form-control input-sm" disabled name="state" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <?php
    $file = fopen('../data_entry_form/data/state.txt', 'r');
    while ($input = fgets($file)) {
        $states = @split(':', $input);
        if ($states[1] == $state) {
            echo '<option value="' . $states[0] . '"  selected="selected">' . $states[1] . '</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="' . $states[0] . '">' . $states[1] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
    ?>
</select>
</html>
```